# QBXML Receive payment showing parsing error in web connector - php Devkit

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I am trying to add customer payment(Receive Payment qbxml) only with payment amount, date and payment method with QBXML but I'm getting the following error from web connector

**QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream**

My QBXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
<ReceivePaymentAddRq>
<ReceivePaymentAdd>
    <CustomerRef>
        <ListID>8000254C-1444671234</ListID>
    </CustomerRef>
    <TxnDate>2021-05-21</TxnDate>
    <RefNumber>2</RefNumber>
    <TotalAmount>100</TotalAmount>
    <PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Cash</FullName></PaymentMethodRef>
</ReceivePaymentAdd></ReceivePaymentAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

I have not added  here because i want to save only payment against customer regardless of invoice no
is it compulsory to add    ??
Can we save only payments against customer into quickbooks using receivepayment qbxml?

Answer (score 1):

The xml is not valid. Take a closer at this line:

```
<PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Cash<FullName/></PaymentMethodRef>
```

There is an opening tag `<FullName>` but is not closing. In stead there is an empty element `<FullName/>` If that would be corrected to  `</FullName>` the xml becomes valid.

Comment: thanks. I corrected to </FullName> but still "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream" error message is appearing

Comment: The xml is now valid. Something else is wrong

Comment: yes and i have checked the qbxml tag sequence. it is also correct. but couldn't find the problem

Comment: Has it something to do with the version 12.0? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004068/3710053

Comment: i have tried <?qbxml version="13.0"?> but still the web connector displaying parsing error..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help but I got the solution to my problem. I read that in my case, "The IsAutoApply flag is used instead of AppliedToTxnAdd. This flag allows QuickBooks to receive the payment without applying it to a specific transaction
If IsAutoApply is false, QuickBooks receives the payment but does not apply it to any outstanding transaction. QuickBooks creates a credit that will appear on the customer job’s next transaction."
So I used false in the qbxml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
<ReceivePaymentAddRq>
<ReceivePaymentAdd>
    <CustomerRef>
        <ListID>8000254C-1444671234</ListID>
    </CustomerRef>
    <TxnDate>2021-05-21</TxnDate>
    <RefNumber>2</RefNumber>
    <TotalAmount>100</TotalAmount>
    <PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Cash</FullName></PaymentMethodRef>
**<IsAutoApply>false</IsAutoApply>**
</ReceivePaymentAdd></ReceivePaymentAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/tutorials/requests-for-receive-payments-bill-payments-and-deposits
this is the reference link.

Comment: off topic but need help. How you are connecting qb desktop with php. Can you share any tutorial?

Comment: @jewelhuq, I am using "QuickBooks PHP DevKit" by Keith Palmer. Please refer to this link https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Does it work with php 7.2? how does it work? any documentation? any video?